# How can I export these 2 variables together on react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I want to make 2 variables for the main colors which can be used on the whole app. Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const primary = '#27bcb5';
const secondary = '#ffffff;
```

How can I export these 2 variables together for using on the app components?

Issue with the solution is :

```js
import  {DefaultStyle}  from './variables';

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const styles = {
  wrapper: {},
  slide1: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: primary,
```

it says can't find variable primary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export them with:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const primary = '#27bcb5';
const secondary = '#ffffff';

export const DefaultStyle = {
    primary,
    secondary,
}
```

So you can use them as:

```js
import { DefaultStyle } from './default-variables';
console.log(DefaultStyle.primary);
console.log(DefaultStyle.secondary);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your solution but when I try to use the variable on the other component it says can't find variable primary. I've added usage example in the above. Must I use it as a object item? 
Like backgroundColor : Defaultstyles.primary

Comment: use this instead: `backgroundColor: DefaultStyle.primary`

Comment: If you want to use variable `primary`, @TimH's answer should works.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a named export. E.g. :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const primary = '#27bcb5';
const secondary = '#ffffff';

export { primary, secondary };
```

After that, you can import your styles via:

```
import { primary, secondary } from 'YOUR_FILE_PATH'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Declarations of colors variables     
  const Maincolor ="#333640"
       const Backgroundcolor = "#FFFFFF"
       const Gridcolor = "#A7A9AB" 
        const colors =  // Made to be bind in one because only one export is possiable 
   {
        Maincolor,
        Backgroundcolor,
        Gridcolor,
    }

    export default  colors; // exporting as default
```

// And in your main code where you have to include

```
import colors from 'path_of_the_file'
// then in styles use 

style ={{backgroundColor:color.Maincolor}} // example how to use
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do something better, define a global file where you can save like Moment() time, Device Measures, etc.

global.js

```
const global = {
  PRIMARY: '#27bcb5',
  SECONDARY: '#ffffff,
  DEVICE_MEASURES:{
     WIDTH: Dimensions.get("window").width,
     HEIGHT: Dimensions.get("window").height;
  },
  ...
}

export default global
```

And then in your code:

```
import GLOBAL from '(directory)/global'

<View style={{ width: GLOBAL.DEVICE_MEASURES.WIDTH }}>
  <Text style={{ color: GLOBAL.PRIMARY }}>
    sup
  </Text>
</View>
```

It's just better to have a global file where you can store all your app's configurations.